# Arriving at the given solution of a product of three vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors, products

I've been given three vectors for which a solution is provided, but I've tried the scalar and dot products and am unable to understand figure out what method was used to obtain the answer.

They did mention this:

t `.` (u `x` v)

Then they gave that the solution is *34*.

But either I don't understand the problem (it's not in English and I'm not very good at the language it's written in) or I just haven't gotten the hang of dot and scalar products properly (I've tried!)

The given vectors whose product is 34, are:

t= 4i - 2j -2k

u= 2i + 4j + 3k

v=  i - 5j + 3k

How is *t`.`(u `x` v)* solved to get *34*? Or do we not evaluate *t`.`(u `x` v)*?

Comment: are you sure the sign of the $k$-component in $u = 2i + 4i \color{red}{+}3k$ is positive?

Comment: I obtain a different result, we should obtain $34$ for $t=-2j-2k$

Comment: Maybe the book has a typo... What signs do you use to obtain 34?

Answer (score 1):

It is known as [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product), we have the cross product

$$u\times v=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\2&4&3\\1&-5&3\end{vmatrix}=(27,-3,-14)$$

and then by dot product

$$t\cdot ( u\times v)=4\cdot 27-2(-3)-2(-14)=142$$

Comment: but how do we arrive at 34? From the method you provided, the solution is 142, not 34.

Comment: could you please check the given vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that these are not the dot and scalar product.

First, the dot-product and the scalar product are two names for the same operation. It corresponds to the first operation, `.` in your expression `t.(u x v)`.

The second operation is called the [cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). It takes two vectors as input and outputs one vector.

Note that in the end, the expression $t.(u\times v)$ is nothing but the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the three vectors.